# Eclipse, problems with getRealPath()

Tags: eclipse, servlets, path, lucene, indexing

I am indexing PDF document using Lucene, I use Eclipse indigo as an IDE and tomcat7 as a servlet container , the problem is when I index the document and want to save the original document for later downloading, but eclipse put the documents in temporary directory in stead of the directory I have chosen.
here is what I am doing.

I have this param in my web.xml

```
    <context-param>
    <description>Location to store uploaded file also the location of files to be indexed</description>
    <param-name>file-upload</param-name>
    <param-value>
    folder\
 </param-value>
</context-param>
```

then calling it inside servlet init() methode like this

```
filePath = getServletContext().getRealPath("") + File.separator + getServletContext().getInitParameter("file-upload");
```

in short I am trying to store the document in directory called "folder" inside my project which is called "Search", but eclipse will store it in the temporary place like this:

```
C:\Users\Solid\Dropbox\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\Search\folder\ir_overview.pdf
```

but the actual path is like this :

```
C:\Users\Solid\Dropbox\workspace\Search\WebContent\folder
```

any idea how to solve this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse deploys the project to a working directory outside of the Project Workspace.

Default, Eclipse uses `/workspace/.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps`
path to deploy web application.

It has to re-organize the files from the directory structure the Eclipse Workspace expects to the format a Web Application expects.

Click on > Servers Tab. Right Click on Servlet container (Tomcat 7 in your case) and Open (F3 is shortcut for eclipse).

You should be able to see Server Path option which contains

> Specify the server path (i.e. catalina.base) and deploy path.

You can specify the deploy location here.

Note: Server must be published with no modules present to make changes.

So, undeploy your web applicaion and change the location.

EDIT:

Unrelated to Question : You should create separate directory out side webContent / webapp to store `Lucene` indexes. This practice would be useful when you deploy application to Tomcat production

Comment: servers -> Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config -> server.xml  I couldn't find it .

Comment: dose this has any relation with what you have told me  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">

Comment: @solid: `server.xml` won't be at that location. You can use "CTRL + SHIFT + R" and then search "server.xml"

Comment: I have found it, but for  some reason it is disabled !!

Answer (score 1):

if you find the fields for the modification disabled on opening the server configuration page, just close your server and remove all the application by right clicking on server > add remove > remove all and after that again right click > then clean. it will un-deploy all the apps currently on the server and will allow you to modify the server settings.